# GoogleSheets, Conditional timeStamp, based on cell value

Tags: javascript, timestamp, google-sheets, conditional-statements

What is the secret behind making this script work based on the number 2 being entered in column 1. Have racked my brain looking at examples of conditions for if-statements, adjusting in various ways, etc. One would think I would've figured it out by now. But no. Not so. Time to leverage some better brains than mine.

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (s.getName() == "Sheet6") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getColumn.getValue() === '2') { //checks the column
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
            nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used Google Spreadsheets before, but based on the code it looks like this function runs every time the sheet is edited, looks at the active cell, and sets an adjacent cell to the current date if the cell is in column 1 and contains the value "2".

Comment: Right, that's the idea.... but it doesn't work for some reason. Debugging doesn't bring up anything. I think the getColumn.getValue part is wrong. But I don't know the proper way to write that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
r.getColumn.getValue()
```

Instead it should be

```
r.getValue()
```

Also I would advice to use "===" instead of "==".

Finally you have to make sure that your Column A is formatted as plain text, or add a condition to your if statement in case "2" is entered as a number.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer, you can drop some API calls by doing:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== "Sheet6" || e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.value !== '2') return;
e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```